# A basic question on least upper bound property

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a closed subset of $\Bbb R$. Let $E$ be any non-empty subset of $S$ which is bounded above in $S$. We need to prove that $E$ has a least upper bound in $S$. Using least upper bound property of $\Bbb R$ we can say that the least upper bound lies in $\Bbb R$, but how to prove that it indeed lies inside $S$.

Closed set : Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then a subset $E$ of $X$ is called closed if it includes all its limit points.

Comment: What properties of $\mathbb R$ *are* you allowed to use?

Comment: What does this question have to do with metric spaces?

Comment: @ChrisCulter: I have changed my problem definition

Comment: @dfeuer: I have used the term "closed set". Thats why metric spaces.

Comment: The term "closed set" relates to the general notion of a "closure operator", and in this context to the notion of "topological closure". You haven't said what definition you're using for a closed set. Please do so.

Comment: @dfeuer did so.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha = \sup(E)$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\alpha - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $E$. Hence, $\exists e\in E$ such that
$$
\alpha - \epsilon < e \leq \alpha
$$
Since $e\in S$,
$$
(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha+\epsilon)\cap S \neq \emptyset
$$
for any $\epsilon > 0$. Since $S$ is closed, $\alpha \in S$ must hold.